# Car race games for raspberry pi

Tags: pi-3b+, games

In my raspberry pi 3 model B+ , I've been looking for some lightweight space car racing games (like torcs and supertuxkart) but I cant Install them as there is no space and will defenitley hang.Is there any games I can Install  (other than supertuxkart and torcs) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an arcade, check out the `supertuxkart`/`extremetuxracer` packages: those are "Mario cart" spin-offs with Linux mascots instead of Nintendo characters.

If you're looking for a racing simulator, check out `torcs`.

In general, Debian has metapackages for popular game genres, e.g. [`racing`](https://blends.debian.org/games/tasks/racing).

Comment: Its not "extremetuxcart" . It is "extremetuxracer".

Comment: there is no game called extremetuxcart.